# Descripción y traducción de medalla Mariscal

Tags: discusión, traducciones, medallas

No entiendo la traducción de esta medalla o a que se refiere, la descripción de la misma es:

> Emplear 500 señaladores útiles.

No entiendo el término **señaladores**, ¿a que se refiere? Además me imagino que el nombre de la medalla tendrá algo que ver con el fútbol americano, pero tampoco entiendo mucho el nombre de esta medalla. Si alguien me pudiera explicar lo agradecería y además clarificar la descripción de esta para el sitio en español. Saludos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Señalador" es la palabra que se ha elegido como traducción de *flag*, "señalas" cuando reportas una publicación como problemática por la razón que sea (mediante el enlace "reportar" de la propia publicación).

Personalmente yo habría traducido esa frase simplemente como "Emitir 500 reportes útiles".

Comment: Estoy totalmente de acuerdo contigo, me parece que "señalar" no es la traducción correcta, de echo "bandera" directamente me parece mas apropiado

Answer (score 4):

Hace algún tiempo noté el término *"señalador"* en *Transifex* (la herramienta que usamos para la traducción de Stack Overflow en español) y comencé a reemplazarlas por *"reporte"*, pero parece que algunas cadenas aún siguen con la traducción antigua.

Voy a revisar de nuevo todas las cadenas con la traducción antigua y reabrir los issues para que [@Juan M](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/4/juan-m) los apruebe.

Cuando estén listos les aviso.

**Actualización:** Juan ya aceptó todas las sugerencias de traducciones con respecto a la palabra *flag*.

Comment: me parece genial, gracias.

Comment: @Héctor Juan ya aceptó todas las sugerencias de traducción. Solo falta que los devs desplieguen de nuevo el sitio actualizado, lo cual posiblemente ocurra en algunas horas.